# signalr hub does not contain a definition for Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am trying to pass some objects to the client from the signalr hub by defining a connectionID however this does not seem to work. as I am getting an error `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.IHubCallerConnectionContext<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Client'`

This is how I call the code:

```
Clients.Client(initiatedBrowserId).mibChoice(connectionId, queriesDictionary, deviceID);
```

here is the whole method as requested:

```
public void DetectDevice(dynamic message)
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        //now we get the connectionID from the table.
        var connectionObj = ConnectionTable[connectionId];

        //we now check whether this is a pathfinder or browser client
        if (connectionObj.clientType == "pathfinder")
        {
            /*The pathfinder initiated the request and so this means the message should be forwarded to the browser client
             that requested this resource*/

            var deviceDiscoveredNotification = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(message);
            var initiatedBrowserId = deviceDiscoveredNotification["browserConnectionID"];
            //message should contain browser client connection id
            if (deviceDiscoveredNotification["data"] == "FOUND")
            {
                //We can base these around device type

                //snmp
                var mibNames = db.OIDs.Select(oid => oid.Mibname).Distinct().ToList();
                //wmi
                var wmiQueries = db.WmiQueries.Select(wmi => wmi.Query).Where(wmi => !wmi.Contains("*")).Distinct().ToList();
                var wmiList = new List<ScheduledMonitoring>();

                var mibList = mibNames.Select(mib => new ScheduledMonitoring(mib, 60)).ToList();

                mibList.AddRange(wmiQueries.Select(wmi => new ScheduledMonitoring(wmi, 60)));

                //Let's construct a data structure that is easy to parse and traverse
                var queriesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<ScheduledMonitoring>>();
                queriesDictionary.Add("snmp", mibList);
                queriesDictionary.Add("wmi", wmiList);

                // pass the pathfinderID along with the mibnames, the pathfinder connectionID
                // needs to also be passed back to the MonitorFeatures  method so we know specifically
                var deviceID = deviceDiscoveredNotification["deviceID"];

                try
                {
                    Clients.Client(initiatedBrowserId).mibChoice(connectionId, queriesDictionary, deviceID);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }

            }
}
```

I know there exists this connection as I can see it in my dictionary which maintains what connectionID maps to who, and if they were to disconnect it would remove them from the dictionary

Comment: can you add the code for your hub and the method you are using to broadcast (where you get the error)?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code for the method

Comment: Try explicitly defining the variable initiatedBrowserId as a string. May be a compiler issue https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2244

Comment: however I am getting a runtime error rather than a compile time error

Comment: so it doesn't work with explicitly defining the string. try this: `var myHubClients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients;
myHubClients.Client(initiatedBrowserId).mibChoice(connectionId, queriesDictionary, deviceID);`